# Python JupyterNotebook: Clear variable?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure how to describe this, so here's the scenario:

I wrote this code and saves as `test.py`:

```
GRAPH = dict()

def clear():
    GRAPH = dict()

def add_to_graph(input):
    GRAPH[input] = None

class Foo:
    pass
```

Now, in a JupyterNotebook cell, I ran:

```
import test

f = test.Foo()
test.add_to_graph(f)
print(test.GRAPH)
```

However, if you ran this cell multiple times, `GRAPH` will contain multiple instance of Foo's:

[image]

I have written a `clear()` function in `test.py` hoping to clear GRAPH in the beginning for repeatability but it doesn't work when I call `test.clear()` in notebook cell

Comment: Not sure I got what you mean by clearing it, if you're trying to del the variable, you can use the `del <variable>` command

Comment: I want to empty the GRAPH every time I ran this cell, so when I print it out, there's always a single FOO instance in the GRAPH

Comment: and I can't make any changes to `add_to_graph` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.clear()` doesn't work as intended, because when you define a variable inside a function, it is created as a local variable that only exists inside the function. So the `GRAPH` inside `test.clear()` is a different object from the `GRAPH` you defined at the top of `test.py`.

One way to get the result you expect is to explicitly refer to the global `GRAPH` variable inside `test.clear()`, defining the function like this:

```py
def clear():
    global GRAPH
    GRAPH = dict()
```

Make sure you force your notebook kernel to import the new version of `test.py`. Then running the cell with a call to `test.clear()` included before `test.add_to_graph(f)` should produce the desired effect.